# Slide in div with fixed header

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wanting to create a div panel with a link which when clicked slides a panel in from the right, I have this working fine but I want to have the clickable link pushed out with the div panel and it's this I cannot figure out although i'm guessing it's really simple.

The html I have is:

```
<div class="quick-contact">

    <div class="slide-toggle">Slide Toggle</div>

            <div class="box">
                    <div class="box-inner">

                    content goes here

                    </div>

            </div>
  </div>
```

the css is this:

```
quick-contact {
  background: #ccc;
  float:right;
 }

 .box{
  float:right;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #f0e68c;
  display: none;
  }

  .slide-toggle {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
  }

  /* Add padding and border to inner content for better animation effect */
.box-inner{
  width: 400px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #a29415;
  }
```

and the jquery is:

```
// use this docu ready //
jQuery(function($) {

      $(".slide-toggle").click(function(){
          $(".box").animate({
                   width: "toggle"
                 });
          });

}); // end
```

I can get the panel to slide when I click the link but the clickable link just sits above the panel when it slides in, I need it to slide out with the panel, I need it to work like this [http://www.sanwebe.com/assets/floating-contact-form/](http://this) The reason i'm not using that example is because I need to slidein panel to slide in the header div and not the body div like this example does.

Comment: you should create an example of the issue you encountered in CODEPEN.io or JSFIDDLE.net

Comment: Thankyou, I will do that in future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just place your `<div class="slide-toggle">...</div>` after `<div class="box">...</div>` (because you are using `float: "right";`). Make it look like this:

```
<div class="quick-contact">        
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-inner">
      content goes here
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide-toggle">
    Slide Toggle
  </div>
</div>
```

Working example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GoPPPE

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/ruo8r7o8/2/

Essentially, what you want to do is:

- Lose the `float` .. it complicates calculations
- Animate the whole box, not just one part

**Javascript action:**

```
$(function(){
    $('.slide-toggle').click(function(){
      $('.quick-contact').animate({
        right: $('.quick-contact').css('right') == '0px' ? "100px": "0px"
      })
    });
  });
```

**CSS action:**

```
.quick-contact {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.slide-toggle {
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  right: -100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou, this also works but can't tick both answers